# how to get all the dates between custom dates?

Tags: php, date

i make a php page in which custom dates are selected i want to get dates between them in an array?here is my code:

```
$startdate1=date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($_POST['registration_opens_date']));
$enddate1=date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($_POST['registration_ends_date']));
```

i used this method but not work for me

```
$begin = $startdate1;
$end = $enddate1;

$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
  echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
}
```

i want to get dates between $startdate1 and $enddate1,how i get dates between them?

Comment: http://boonedocks.net/mike/archives/137-Creating-a-Date-Range-Array-with-PHP.html that example might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are severals ways, for exampe:

```
$startdate1  = "2014-01-01";   //here set start date
$startdate1  = strtotime($startdate1 ); // Convert date to a UNIX timestamp  

$enddate1  = "2014-01-05";  //here set end date
$enddate1  = strtotime($enddate1 ); // Convert date to a UNIX timestamp  

// Loop from the start date to end date and output all dates inbetween  
for ($i = $startdate1; $i <= $enddate1 ; $i += 86400) {  
    echo date("Y-m-d", $i) . '<br />';  
}
```

Also from PHP v =>3.4 you can use such classes as `DateInterval`,  `DatePeriod`:

```
$startdate1   = new DateTime( '2014-01-01' );

$enddate1   = new DateTime( '2014-01-07' );
$enddate1   = $enddate1->modify( '+1 day' );

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($startdate1, $interval ,$enddate1  );

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
}
```